# tortoisegit diff shows unmodified files

Tags: git, tortoisegit

Tortoisegit diff shows unmodified files with 0 lines added with 'Modified' status.
Actually it shows all project files.

So how to diff only modified files?

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like a bug in tortoisegit. Use git on the command line (e.g. in a git bash) to get accurate information:

```
> git status
```

I also found above command to weirdly enough also update tortoisegit's output on next call...